# How to get the value of a "transfer_all" transaction?

Tags: polkadot

my question is regarding Polkadot, I need to get the value of any "transfer" transactions and there's no problem with it with "transfer_keep_alive" and "transfer" transactions. On "transfer_all", however, extrinsics don't contain the "value". I got a clue that I need to get events of a block via `state_getStorage` RPC method, but I'm struggling with which keys I should provide as params. There's not much info in docs about it. Also, I'm not using a polkadot-js lib and only use HTTP RPC requests. How do I get the events for the block via `state_getStorage` method?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [Substrate API Sidecar's](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar) `GET block` endpoint. It will give you all the events associated with each extrinsic.

Sidecar is stateless and requires very few system resources. Just give it a WS connection to a node and use the [Sidecar API](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate-api-sidecar/dist/).

Comment: Can't use it for my use case as I can't have WS connections (hence "I'm not using a polkadot-js lib and only use HTTP RPC requests"). There are several ways I could get these events from API, however, the easiest of the ways are not available for me.

Comment: They are under `system.events`: `0x26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef780d41e5e16056765bc8461851072c9d7`

Comment: Yes, there is an RPC method ```state_getStorage``` that supposedly should allow to request events. However, there is very little documentation of what are the "keys" that are supposed to be associated with certain data in storage. On my Polkadot node the ```state_getKeys``` method, which is supposed to be called with 0 arguments, returns an error that it expects 1 or more arguments. Seems like the documentation is partially deprecated, since my node is running the latest version.